# Not able to record Jmeter requests of Flutter app

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have tried existing answers but didn't succeed.
I have tried with **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** of Jmeter and I am **not able to capture Application requests of my apk** in Jmeter while I am able to get some connectivity check requests such as 'connectivitycheck.gstatic.com' and 'www.google.com'.

I have also tried using **blazemeter** as well (https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889) but didn't captured. **Using that I am able to captures all the requests from Phone's browser but NOT application requests.**

I am using Jmeter Ver. 5.5, Android Emulator with API 34 x86_64. Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you're setting the proxy in correct place? Emulator has [its own proxy settings](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#proxy):

   [image]
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries (it will be a good idea to [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder)
3. Both HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder are only capable of capturing HTTP or HTTPS traffic, if your application uses other network protocol(s) you will have to find another way of intercepting requests like using [a sniffer tool](https://techwiser.com/wireshark-alternatives-for-android/)

Comment: Yes all my settings are correct and as shown above also tried same above setup but didn't worked. I am using Flutter App for android.